# Combine multiple lists into one list and order by amount

Tags: c#, linq

Combine multiple lists into one list and order by amount

I have a class like this

```
public class PriceList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

First list. It's called VOne

```
Name    Amount  Price
P5      5000    6
P10     10000   10
P20     20000   20
```

Second list. It's called VTwo

```
Name    Amount  Price
P5      5000    5
P10     10000   10
P15     15000   15
P20     20000   21
```

Third list. It's called VThree

```
Name    Amount  Price
P1      1000    1
P10     10000   9
P20     20000   19
```

I want the result like this

```
Name    Amount  VOne    VTwo    VThree
P1      1000    0       0       1
P5      5000    6       5       0
P10     10000   10      10      9
P15     15000   0       15      0       
P20     20000   20      21      19
```

This is what I try. It works but seems sophisticated. I need the simpler way to do this. Linq will be prefered but I have no idea how to use it.

```
static void Test()
{
    var VOne = new List<PriceList>(new[]
    {
        new PriceList { Name = "P5", Amount = 5000, Price = 6},
        new PriceList { Name = "P10", Amount = 10000   , Price = 10},
        new PriceList { Name = "P20", Amount = 20000, Price = 20}
    });

    var VTwo = new List<PriceList>(new[]
    {
        new PriceList { Name = "P5", Amount = 5000, Price = 5},
        new PriceList { Name = "P10", Amount = 10000   , Price = 10},
        new PriceList { Name = "P15", Amount = 10000   , Price = 15},
        new PriceList { Name = "P20", Amount = 20000, Price = 21}
    });

    var VThree = new List<PriceList>(new[]
    {
        new PriceList { Name = "P1", Amount = 5000, Price = 1},
        new PriceList { Name = "P10", Amount = 10000   , Price = 9},
        new PriceList { Name = "P20", Amount = 20000, Price = 19}
    });

    var prices = new List<PriceListResult>();
    foreach (var m in VOne)
    {
        var exist = prices.Any(x => x.Name == m.Name && x.Amount == m.Amount);
        if (!exist)
            prices.Add(new PriceListResult { Name = m.Name, Amount = m.Amount });
    }

    foreach (var m in VTwo)
    {
        var exist = prices.Any(x => x.Name == m.Name && x.Amount == m.Amount);
        if (!exist)
            prices.Add(new PriceListResult { Name = m.Name, Amount = m.Amount });
    }

    foreach (var m in VThree)
    {
        var exist = prices.Any(x => x.Name == m.Name && x.Amount == m.Amount);
        if (!exist)
            prices.Add(new PriceListResult { Name = m.Name, Amount = m.Amount });
    }

    prices = prices.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ThenBy(x => x.Amount).ToList();
    foreach (var price in prices)
    {
        var v1 = VOne.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == price.Name && x.Amount == price.Amount);
        if (v1 != null)
            price.VOne = v1.Price;

        var v2 = VTwo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == price.Name && x.Amount == price.Amount);
        if (v2 != null)
            price.VTwo = v2.Price;

        var v3 = VThree.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == price.Name && x.Amount == price.Amount);
        if (v3 != null)
            price.VThree = v3.Price;
    }
}

public class PriceListResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int VOne { get; set; }
    public int VTwo { get; set; }
    public int VThree { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be that you spend some time get acquainted to [the standard LINQ methods](https://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx)

You can use `Enumerable.Concat` to put your three sequences into one sequence, then you can use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-5.0) to make groups of `PriceLists` that have the same amount. User parameter `resultSelector` to create one object per Amount and PriceLists with this Amount.

The problem is, that if you've got a `PriceList`, you can't see whether it is a `PriceList`  of vOne, vTwo or vThree. So from every Price we'll have to remember the Amount, the Price and from which priceList the data originated.

I'll do it in small steps, so it is easy to see what is done. If you want, you can put it in one big LINQ. As all statements use delayed execution, this will not improve performance, however one big LINQ will deteriorate readability.

```
var vOne = VOne.Select(priceList => new
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = priceList.Name,
    Amount = priceList.Amount,
    Price = priceList.Price,
});
var vTwo = Select(priceList => new
{
    Id = 2,
    Name = priceList.Name,
    Amount = priceList.Amount,
    Price = priceList.Price,
});
vThree = Select(priceList => new
{
    Id = 3,
    Name = priceList.Name,
    Amount = priceList.Amount,
    Price = priceList.Price,
});
var allPriceLists = vOne.Concat(vTwo).Concat(vThree);
```

Make groups of sequences that have the same value for the combination [Name, Amount]. Use parameter resultSelector to create one object per group

```
var result = allPriceLists.GroupBy(priceList => new {priceList.Name, priceList.Amount},

    // parameter resultSelector: use every [Name, Amount] combination,
    // with all priceLists that have this combination to make one new:
    (nameAmountCombinatin, priceListsWithThisCombination) => new
    {
        Name = nameAmountCombination.Name,
        Amount = nameAmountCombination.Amount,
        Vone = priceListsWithThisCombination
                   .Where(priceList => priceList.Id == 1)
                   .Select(priceList => priceList.Amount)
                   .FirstOrDefault(),
        Vtwo = priceListsWithThisCombination
                   .Where(priceList => priceList.Id == 2)
                   .Select(priceList => priceList.Amount)
                   .FirstOrDefault(),
        Vthree = priceListsWithThisCombination
                   .Where(priceList => priceList.Id == 3)
                   .Select(priceList => priceList.Amount)
                   .FirstOrDefault(),
    })
```

Note: I assume that in Vone (etc.) doesn't have two PriceLists with the same [name, amount] combination. If you allow that Vone has two elements with [P5, 5000], consider to Sum the Amounts

If there is a missing Amount in one of the original PriceLists, you will get the default value for Price: 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var all = list1.Union(list2).Union(list3).ToList();
```

then:

```
 var grouped = all.GroupBy(p => new {
      p.Name,
      p.Amount
 });
```

finally:

```
var results = grouped.Select(p => new {
      p.Name,
      p.Amount,
      Price = string.Join(", ", p.Select(x => x.Price))
}).ToList().OrderBy(item => item.Amount);

var finalResult = results.Select(item => new PriceListResult {
                 Name  = item.Name,
                 Amount = item.Amount ,
                 VOne = Price.Split(new[] { ','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray()[0],
                 VTwo = Price.Split(new[] { ','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray()[1],
                 VThree = Price.Split(new[] { ','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray()[2]
                 }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

make class like this:

```
public class PriceList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string type {get;set;}
}
```

Then:

```
var list1Typed = List1.ForEach(f => f.type = "VOne");
var list2Typed = List2.ForEach(f => f.type = "VTwo");
var list3Typed = List3.ForEach(f => f.type = "VThree");
var all = list1Typed.Union(list2Typed).Union(list3Typed).ToList();

var allComplete = all.GroupBy(g => g.Name).Select(s =>
   new PriceListResult(){
      Name = g.Key,
      Amount = g.First().Amount,
      VOne = g.Any(a => a.Type == "VOne") ? g.Where(w => w.Type =="VOne").Sum(s => s.Amount) : 0,
      VTwo = g.Any(a => a.Type == "VTwo ") ? g.Where(w => w.Type =="VTwo").Sum(s => s.Amount) : 0,
     VThree = g.Any(a => a.Type == "VThree") ? g.Where(w => w.Type =="VThree").Sum(s => s.Amount) : 0
}).OrderBy(o => o.Amount).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited Kai's answer and it works

```
var results = list1.Union(list2).Union(list3)
.GroupBy
(
    p => p.Name,
    p => p,
    (key, list) => new { Name = key, Amount = list.First().Amount, List = list }
)
.Select(s => new
{
    Name = s.Name,
    Amount = s.Amount,
    VOne = list1.Where(x => x.Name == s.Name && x.Amount == x.Amount).Select(x => x.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
    VTwo = list2.Where(x => x.Name == s.Name && x.Amount == x.Amount).Select(x => x.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
    VThree = list3.Where(x => x.Name == s.Name && x.Amount == x.Amount).Select(x => x.Price).FirstOrDefault()
})
.OrderBy(o => o.Amount).ToList();
```